# covert Multi line into single line with grep name

Tags: shell-script, shell, text-processing, command-line

Can you please help me this.

```
item : name_1 
       213321654
       32549846546
item : name_2 
       8563161631
item : name_3
       96315242161
       73216510631
       51654316416
```

Need to convert

```
item : name_1  213321654 32549846546
item : name_2  8563161631
item : name_3  96315242161 73216510631  51654316416
```

Comment: what did you try? why do you think `grep` is the appropriate tool for it?

Answer (score 0):

this is work for awk not grep

```
awk 'NF==1 { printf " %s", $1 } 
     NF>1 { printf "%s%s",l,$0; l="\n" ;} 
     END { printf "%s",l ;}'
```

main trick is to use `printf` to avoid inserting a new line.

Comment: t working but If any two variables it coming on second line like this. can help me this.

`item : name_1  `
 `             213321654 32549846546`
`item : name_2  8563161631`
`item : name_3  `
`             96315242161 73216510631  51654316416`
I need change single line like below

`item : name_1  213321654 32549846546`
`item : name_2  8563161631`
`item : name_3  96315242161 73216510631  51654316416`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variant of the well-known sed oneliner for conditionally joining lines:

```
$ sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n[[:space:]]\{1,\}/ /;ta' -e 'P;D' file
item : name_1  213321654 32549846546
item : name_2  8563161631
item : name_3 96315242161 73216510631 51654316416
```

See for example [Sed One-Liners Explained, Part I: File Spacing, Numbering and Text Conversion and Substitution](https://catonmat.net/sed-one-liners-explained-part-one)